# Restrain access to some pages for editors/authors/members in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I try to manage roles and capabilities of my members. What I need, is to mirror Editor/Author/Subscriber of Wordpress for pages.

My website is done to present multiple bands of my association :

- Each band will have editors for his own page (only).
- Each subscriber/author/editor have at least one band.
- Band pages can have subpages private or not (seen only by band members), e.g. private page of band A can't be seen/edited by Editors of band B.
- Editors/Authors can write public articles.

I try many plugin like Groups, Advanced Access Manager, Nav Menu Roles, Press Permit Core, User Specific Content,... but I'm not able to do what I want. I'm sure some of those plugin can help but I don't know how to proceed simply.

I finally found some plugin for doing what I need:
http://wordpress.org/plugins/bu-section-editing/

Multi-Site was not an option for me as [this link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Before_You_Create_A_Network#Do_you_really_need_a_network.3F) suggest.

Thanks for your answer it helps me to discover multi-site and find what I need.

Comment: Sounds like you need [Wordpress Multisite](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network)

Comment: Will it keep a global coherence for theme ? Each page will be converted to a site ?

Comment: There are lots of options. Yes, you can enforce a single theme for all sites.